# MySql insert data in wrong order from JPA

Tags: mysql, jpa

I am trying to import the data from excel ile to different tables in my DB.
The import is done , the only problem is that some of the data is in the wrong order[image].

This is what my excel file loks like.
And this is what the data in my Bd lokks like.
[image]

My service file has this method:

```
@Override
public List<Task> getTasksFromExcel(MultipartFile files) throws IOException {
    List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(files.getInputStream());
    XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    String a = "A";
    for (int index = 0; index <= worksheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); index++) {
        if (index > 1) {
            Task task = new Task();
            Lot lot = new Lot();
            String ref = a + index;
            CellReference cr = new CellReference(ref);
            XSSFRow row = worksheet.getRow(cr.getRow());

            String lotName = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            Lot existingLot = lotRepository.findByName(lotName);
            if (existingLot == null) {
                lot.setName(lotName);
                lotRepository.save(lot);
            } else {
                lot = existingLot;
            }
            ;
            task.setName(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
            String email = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
            Collaborator collab = collaboratorRepository.findByEmail(email);
            task.setCollaborator(collab);
            List<Double> iC = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
                iC.add((Double) row.getCell(i).getNumericCellValue());
            }
            Set<Double> charge = new HashSet<Double>();
            charge.addAll(iC);
            task.setInitialCharge(charge);
            task.setLot(lot);

            taskList.add(task);
            taskRepository.save(task);

        }
    }
    return taskList;
}
```

And for the entity definition I go tthis.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
public class Task {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String name;
private String description;
private Date assignment;
private Date deadline;
@ElementCollection
private Set<Double> initialCharge=new HashSet<Double>();
@Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(32)")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Status status = Status.TODO;
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "lot_id")
private Lot lot;
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "collaborator_id")
private Collaborator collaborator;
```

Comment: *the only problem is that some of the data is in the wrong order* No order exists in a table - it is a heap. Do not pay attention. Apply proper ORDER BY in your queries for definite records order.

Comment: I want the first added to be the first written in the DB, how could I do that?

Comment: It was written first. But not to the physically first place - this is a norma. I'll repeat - "order" term in a table not exists. At all. Dataset which you see on the screen is a result of a query (like `SELECT * FROM table`), not table content. It has no ORDER BY clause - so records order in output is random. You cannot do something with it - this is a dogma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mapped this differently then your excel spreadsheet, and so lose the S1,S2,S3 column name/ordering you had for the single Task row, and seemed to have assumed that the set positional would be consistent, giving you S1-S3 for free. It does not.

Normalizing this out to allow expanding lists of charges and still having an order would mean adding a positional column to the task_initial_charges table. JPA will populate this column behind the scenes if you simply annotate your element collection with the [OrderColumn](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html) to specify it:

The task_initial_charge needs s1,s2,s3 columns so that a single task_id has 3 positional columns, or you need another column in there to allow writing out the position within your initialCharge Set.

```
@ElementCollection
@OrderColumn
private Set<Double> initialCharge=new HashSet<Double>();
```

The order of the initialCharge set when the entity is persisted will then be stored in the database, and should be used when fetching the entity.